# How can I store credentials and access them from viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm, kotlin-stateflow

I have a ViewModel that I use to login with.

First time I login I save the username and password to a DataStore (from the main ActivityContext)

Next time I open the app I load the user information from the DataStore and use that to login automatically.

I think it is too low cohesion when I manage my DataStore from the MainActivity when I only use it in the ViewModel, and I have to do a lot of unnecessary collection from redundant StateFlows that I don't think I need.

My viewmodel has a function `login()` which will add the user to the `user` state of the viewmodel if the login was successfull (this is used in the mainactivity wo listens for updates on that state)

```kotlin
class UserViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val userRepository = UserRepository()
    private val _token = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Token>>(Resource.Loading())
    val token: StateFlow<Resource<Token>> = _token
    private val _user = MutableStateFlow<Resource<User>>(Resource.Loading())
    val user: StateFlow<Resource<User>> = _user

    fun login(user: User) = viewModelScope.launch {
        _token.value = Resource.Loading()
        _token.value = userRepository.auth(user)
        if (token.value is Resource.Success) {
            _user.value = Resource.Success(user)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

My MainActivity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel: UserViewModel by viewModels()


    private val Context.userPreferencesDataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(
        name = "user"
    )

    private fun useUser() {
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted{
                viewModel.user.collect{ user ->
                userPreferencesDataStore.edit { ds ->
                    user.data?.let {
                        ds[USER] = setOf(it.username, it.password)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            userPreferencesDataStore.data.collect {
                it[USER].let { usr ->
                    if (usr != null) {
                        viewModel.login(User(usr.first(), usr.last()))
                    } else {
                        viewModel.error("No user yet")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

How can I get move the logic of saving and loading the saved user credentials into the viewmodel and avoid all this redundancy?

Comment: As the answer below suggests, the complete solution would be to have a Dependency Injection (inversion) flow and have the DataSource injected to your view model. A simple solution would be to have an init(dataStore: DataSource) method in your ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to inject the datastore into the viewmodel but maybe I should only inject the flow of the datastore.

Comment: When you say "inject" what do you mean? viewModel.setDataSource(datasource) is also "injecting" as the dependency is injected to the view model.

Comment: By instantiating the viewmodel with the datastore in the constructor.

Comment: Injecting by constructor means you can't use "by viewModels()", without using a dependency injection framework. This is why I suggested the setter/init methods. If you want to go with the dependency injection framework you can check Hilt: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

Comment: could I just use manual dependency injection?

Comment: You can use whatever you want.. I do recommend reading about Android dependency injection though, because it's how Android apps are written today.